# Algebra: removing similar terms [ x-(x*0.25)=3]

Tags: zero, algebra

I was trying to solve this on my own but was having trouble isolating the x:

```
x - (x * 0.25) = 3
```

On algebra.com, it was converted like so:

```
x - (x * 0.25) = 3
(1 - 0.25) * x = 3     [*** question 1]
```

And then continues to solve for zero:

```
(75 / 100) * x = 3
75 * x / 100 = 3
75 * x / 100 - 3 = 0   [*** question 2]
.75 * x - 3 = 0
0 = 0
x = 4
```

[* question 1] how is this statement derived? This doesn't seem like distribution.

[* question 2] why solve for zero?

[* question 3] Is there a simpler way to combine like values and solve the equation?

Comment: Perhaps this belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Factor x out of the left hand side. x - (x*0.25) => (1-0.25)*x

2 Computers have to do trial and error to get results, it's looking for whatever will make that equal zero. People can do it a lot more intrinsically.

3

> ```
> x - (x/4) = 3   -- multiply everything by 4
> 4x - x = 12     -- suddenly looks a lot easier
> 3x = 12         -- 4 - 1 = 3      
> x = 4           -- 12 / 3 = 4
> ```

Comment: Your answer to question 3 is very helpful.Re: question 1: The factoring gets me because of the flip in the order of the elements.

Comment: You don't need the brackets in order for the order of the operations to be correct, so write it as x - x*0.25 = x(1-0.25) = (1-0.25)x.

Answer (score 0):

```
x - (x * .25)       = 3
(x * 1) - (x * .25) = 3
x * (1 - .25)       = 3
x * .75             = 3
x                   = 3 / .75
x                   = 4
```

You don't have to solve for zero.  Using automated tools to solve math problems may give you a correct answer (and correct intermediate steps) but they won't always give you the best or clearest of either.

Comment: I like the style of reduction here. The factoring out of the x using 1 is still fuzzy to me.